# Playwright nodejs giving - page.goto: net::ERR_ABORTED; maybe frame was detached?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, playwright, playwright-test

- I am developing a UI testing web application
- There are two schemas known as "testsuites" and another known as
  "testcases."
- Each "testcase" contains the URL of the web application to be tested
  and a corresponding "testsuiteId."
- I need to execute a specific "testsuite," so I am iterating over each
  "testcase" and utilizing the **page.goto(url)** function in every
  iteration.
- In the provided code, the execution flows from the **runTestSuite** function to the **performActions** function with each iteration."

```
public runTestSuite = async (testSuiteId: number) => {
        let result: any = 'Failed';
        const finalArraySet = await this.fetchAllTestCasesAndMakeArray(testSuiteId);
        await this.createBrowserInstance();

        for (const testCase of finalArraySet) {
            const { id, url, actions }: any = Object.values(testCase)[0];

            if (actions.length > 0) {
                result = await this.performAction!.performActions(actions, url);
                if (result) {
                    result = 'Success';
                } else {
                    result = 'Failed';
                }

                // writing result of testCase into testResults table
                const [, created] = await TestResult.findOrCreate({
                    where: { testCaseId: id },
                    defaults: {
                        testCaseId: id,
                        executionDate: new Date(),
                        result: result
                    }
                });

                if (!created) {
                    await TestResult.update(
                        {
                            executionDate: new Date(),
                            result: result
                        },
                        {
                            where: { testCaseId: id }
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        // writing result of testSuite into testSuiteResults table
        const [, created] = await TestSuiteResult.findOrCreate({
            where: { testSuiteId },
            defaults: {
                testSuiteId,
                executionDate: new Date(),
                result: result
            }
        });

        if (!created) {
            await TestSuiteResult.update(
                {
                    executionDate: new Date(),
                    result: result
                },
                {
                    where: { testSuiteId }
                }
            );
        }
        return result;
    };
```

```
public async performActions(
        actions: Action[],
        url: string
    ): Promise<boolean> {
        let isSuccess = true;
        try {
            if (this.page) {
                await this.page.goto(url);
                for (const action of actions) {
                    const actionResult = await this.playwrightAction.performActionAndWriteResult(action);
                    if (actionResult === false) {
                        isSuccess = false;
                    }
                }
                return isSuccess;
            } else {
                logger.error('Page is undefined');
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (err: any) {
            logger.error(`it's an critical error>>>>>>>> ${err.message}`);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The below error occurs in the **performActions** function at the line **this.page.goto(url)**.

```
page.goto: net::ERR_ABORTED; maybe frame was detached?\n=========================== logs ===========================\nnavigating to \"https://uat1.agyield.com/agyield/\", waiting until \"load\"\n============================================================
```

I have tried to put **timeout** also in **page.goto**, but it still not working.

Comment: Whew, this is a lot of spaghetti. Maybe take a step back and describe what you're trying to do, then provide a [mcve] formatted by [prettier](https://prettier.io/playground/) and without noisy console logs everywhere. Why are you writing all of these rather bizarre abstractions? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I attempted to optimize my question.

Comment: Thanks, that's better, but I'm still missing a good deal of code necessary to make this runnable. What are `fetchAllTestCasesAndMakeArray`, `playwrightAction.performActionAndWriteResult`, `TestResult`, etc? These abstractions seem unnecessary and hard to debug since they presumably return booleans instead of actual Playwright errors.